# Node JS serialport 5 wrong buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

I have a problem with node js and the node module "serialport" version 5.

- SerialPort Version: 4.0.7 & 5.x
- NodeJS Version: 6.11.3 LTS
- Operating System and Hardware Platform: Debian ARMv7

### **Summary of Problem**

As i used version 4.0.7 i got the following buffer result:

```
<Buffer 55 00 0a 07 01 eb a5 00 00 80 08 01 81 38 3f 00 03 ff ff ff ff 47 00 8d>
```

Now i'm using version 5.x and now i get the following buffer result:

```
<Buffer b1 31 4c fc>
```

As you can see the length is different. And the buffer on version 4.0.7 always starts with 55 (that's what is correct)

### Steps and Code to Reproduce the Issue

```
port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyS3', { baudrate: 57600 });

port.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err.message);
});

port.on('data', function(buf) {
    console.log(buf);
});
```

Does someone know why i'm getting a wrong buffer?

Comment: `baudrate` should be `baudRate`, according to the manual.

Comment: You are a hero <3

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, `baudrate` should be `baudRate` (capital R).